# Finding The Number Of The Solutions For $\cos x = \frac{x^2}{100}$

Tags: trigonometry

Hello everyone how can I find the number of the solution to the equation:

$\cos x = \frac{x^2}{100}$ in real numbers?

I tried to convert it to function $y = \frac{x^2}{100} -\cos x$
and find all the cutting points with the x axis by find all the extreme points of y.

$y' = \frac{x}{50}+\sin x$

I found 1 minimum point in $(0,-1)$ because of that I know that the equation have
at least two solutions.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hint: can you find a lower and upper bound for the maximal value of x for which the equality holds for the _last_ time?

Comment: Hint : draw a graph. Find values of both side on the numbers 0 and π/2 . Also note that that both the functions are even. Also in the range 0 to π/2, check the behaviour of both sides, i.e increasing or decreasing. Last thing , check when the right side will cross the value of 1 , so that they stop intersecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a rough plot will give you 6 solutions

Draw the graph of $\cos x$ , and notice that $\cos x\le 1$ , and ${x^2\over 100} > 1$ for all $x$ such that $|x| > 10$ , so there won't be any solution before $x=-10$ and after $x=10$ . Now , a rough plot of graph between $x=-10$ and $x=10$ , will give you 6 points of intersection.[image]!

Comment: Thank you but I didn't understand the last part.

Comment: Could you please elaborate exactly what you didn't understand ? I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: Never mind I understood your solution. Thank you very much!!!